# Form Submit to Data Extension, then email form contents

Tags: marketing-cloud

Here is the scenario.

1. form submitted
2. redirect to thank you page
3. data extension gets data from form
4. email to fire off with the content from that form submit

I have successfully built all the pieces that inject the data into the DE. I can even fire off the email using triggered send. But now I am stuck at how to pass that content into the email.

The form page is pretty simple 
[image]

And the thank you page has SSJS like this. And like I said I have no issues getting data into the DE. I want to send this submitted content to a specific email address for processing. I am now just stumped on how to put the content in the email.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to accomplish this.

1. When calling triggeredSend.Send(), pass in the attributes that are needed in the email:

> var status = triggeredSend.Send("aruiz@example.com", {FirstName:"Angel", CouponCode:"AA1AF"});

Example from documentation: https://help.exacttarget.com/fi/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/triggered_send_server_side_javascript_functions/

2. If the Email Address field in the DE in a unique value, then you could use the AMPScript Lookup() function (or similar SSJS function) in the body of the email to pull in the values from the Data Extension based on the key.

Details on Lookup() function: https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/

Answer (score 0):

Mac thank you.

I used the #1 solution you provided. Took a bit to understand that I had to declare the variables for each field on the thank you page and then use the  {FirstName:"Angel", CouponCode:"AA1AF"} to declare the AMPscript variables for the email-- such as {FirstName... then the challenge was to figure how to properly code the variable in place of the static content that was shown in the example. Example being that Angel and AA1AF in this {FirstName:"Angel", CouponCode:"AA1AF"} are static and to put the variable into this you remove the quoted words and replace with the variable such as {FirstName:fName, CouponCode:cCode}

I must admit the documentation is not friendly to a newbie.

Thanks for the help.